# Can I directly learn Javascript before HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, performance

I have very less basic knowledge of html and CSS, should I start learning Javascript?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. HTML for the view purpose
2. CSS for adding the styles
3. Javascript is for writing the data logic and also you can change the view of the HTML and CSS using javascript.

So everything goes hand in hand . You can start learning Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Yes and no:

It's how I started out. You could start off by learning real JavaScript, or start off simple with Khan Academy's processingJS courses (learning to make shapes and simple games using their modified JavaScript)

HTML and CSS, however, do provide a lot of basics for coding knowledge. Additionally, you can do a lot more with JavaScript with HTML and CSS.

Either way, it still works out. My recommendation is that you learn HTML and CSS first, since they're a bit more simple, and give you some basics of coding. Then, you'll have a bit of an easier time with JavaScript.

Hope this helps.